# Consistent view modes in Dolphin FM

Tags: kubuntu, kde, filemanager, dolphin

When using Dolphin, each folder seems to have its own configuration for view modes. Meaning that if I change my view mode to "details" and then go into another folder that has "icons" as it's view mode, it just reverts back to icons..

Is there any way to disable folder specific view modes and have it just respect the view mode I chose?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Dolphin view properties**

## 1

Dolphin > Settings > Configure Dolphin > General; Behavior tab - View Properties: Remember view properties for each folder / Use common view properties for all folders.

[image]

## 2

Dolphin > View > Adjust View Properties > Apply View Properties To: Current folder / Current folder including all sub-folders / All folders

[image]

## 3

This information is from the https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2010-July/004494.html

Open the Dolphin in the ~/.kde/share/apps/dolphin/view_properties/global/   (*1) and turn the Icons/Details/Columns/Preview/... on/off. The settings are saved to the ~/.kde/share/apps/dolphin/view_properties/global/.directory file and used as the global defaults - IF the local folder does not have own .directory file with the overriding settings.

KDE .directory file:

The .directory file is a KDE folder view properties file. It contains the folder viewing settings for a directory in KDE. It includes settings such as icon positions and view mode (icon, list, etc.). Automatically created when the view settings of a folder are modified. Hidden by default.

(*1) If the ~/.kde/share/apps/dolphin/view_properties/global/ directory does not exist, you could make it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel silly for not having found that myself :)

Comment: Wow that wars a great answer, thanks so much was dealing with this problem as well